# angular $resource send request with DELETE method and request body get 415 error

Tags: angularjs, resources

I send a delete quest via angular $resource, however it always get 415 error and the request body was turn to string looks like a get request.

```
'use strict';

(function(angular, window){

var authsys = angular.module('authsysApp');

authsys.factory('$_privilege', ['$resource', '$q', '$notify', function($resource, $q, $notify){

    var resource = {
        //删除权限
        batchRemovePrivilege: $resource(window.ctxPath + '/rolepri/batchDeletePrivilegeFromRole', {}, {delete:{method: 'DELETE'}})
    };

    return {
        batchRemovePrivilege: batchRemovePrivilege
    };

    function batchRemovePrivilege(params){

        var q = resource.batchRemovePrivilege.delete(params).$promise;
        return q.then(function(){
            return true;
        });
    }


}]);

})(angular, window);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a header to your request:

```
var resource = {
    //删除权限
    batchRemovePrivilege: function(params){
           return $http({
                method: 'DELETE',
                url: window.ctxPath + '/rolepri/batchDeletePrivilegeFromRole',
                data: params,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
           });
    }
};
```

**execute:**

```
var q = resource.batchRemovePrivilege(params).$promise;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, as we use ngResource to do the interactive job so i don't want to break this rule. can't we achieve aim via ngResource?

Comment: Try add the header to $resource. return $resource(window.ctxPath + '/rolepri/batchDeletePrivilegeFromRole', {}, {delete:{method: 'DELETE'}, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }})

Comment: Thanks @Tal.
Adding headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} worked for me.